# Excel help - Formula multiple criteria on a different tab

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have shown an image of two tabs on the same worksheet - Jan and Jan P & L.
The Jan P and L is a huge document with a lot of information, the Jan tab is a review of the data on the P & L. I want to use a formula that extract the value from the P & L tab that exactly matches the cost Centre and the Category. It needs to have an IF Error so that if blank, it returns no value at all.

Can anyone advise please?

[image]

Comment: A "tab" is a **worksheet**; those are different worksheets in one **workbook**.

Answer (score 0):

SUMIFS is a great formula for this, especially if you're okay showing a "0" when a match is not found. If you want a "blank", then it will need some tweaks.

For the sake of simplicity, we're placing all data on one sheet here. Adjust your formula as needed.

Cell C3 formula:

```
=SUMIFS(I:I,G:G,A3,H:H,B3)
```

So it's summing column I where both A and B match G and H rows. Since you'll never have repetitive G&H, then SUMIFS works.

[image]

**EDIT**
Adding another picture to demonstrate the order does not matter. Also, use this formula if you would like to display a blank rather than 0 when a match is not found:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(G:G,A3,H:H,B3)>0,SUMIFS(I:I,G:G,A3,H:H,B3),"")
```

So this formula will perform the SUMIFS portion if COUNTIFS finds a match, else blank.

[image]

Comment: thank you, so the sheet is super large and the review sheet will not always match rows on the p&l tab. For that reason i need it to find the value when it exactly matches cost centre and cat

Comment: And that's what this formula does. Nothing needs to be in the same order.

Comment: I understand how to tweak a formula as an if error to get blanks, I jut cant find one that works for this - this looks promising

Comment: thank you will give this a go - much appreciated

Comment: You'll never receive an error with this formula, but rather, will return a 0. I've edited the answer by adding another formula if you would rather return a blank.

Comment: Thanks for your help - Solved with this: =IFERROR(SUMIFS('JAN P&L'!$C:$C,'JAN P&L'!$A:$A,JAN!A48,'JAN P&L'!$B:$B,JAN!B48),"")